# fadeIn addClass on fixed header after scrollpoint jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, delay, fadein, offset

New to the forums here and hoping that someone can help me out.

Having a little bit of an issue with trying to make a fixed header fadein a class that gets applied to it once the user scrolls past a certain point.

Here is the code that I am using below:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(".header-container").offset().top>385){
       $(".header-container").fadeIn(200).addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
       $(".header-container").fadeOut(200).removeClass("sticky");
   }
});
```

you can view the page that I'm trying to get working here:

http://v2.blue-square.com.au

You will notice that when the page loads you can view the logo and the navigation up the top. The moment that you start scrolling it disappears. I don't want that to happen. I want that .header-container to stay where it is and be visible. Once it reaches a scroll point on the page the class 'sticky' (basically sticky contains a background image, changes the logo over and changes the colour of the navigation links) gets added to the .header-container div and fades it in. When the user scrolls back up I want it to remove the class 'sticky' and have the navigation appear as it does when the site loads for the first time. The header should not be hidden at all.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the `else` part has problems,

```
else
{
    $(".header-container").fadeOut(200).removeClass("sticky");
}
```

THe `fadeOut`  hides the element(`.header-container`) by fading it to transparent, and add an `attribute style` with `display:none` property.

To solve this problem try:

```
else
{
    $(".header-container").removeClass("sticky");
}
```

Refer site for `fadeOut` http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: Thanks @RohanKumar that works to a degree. I was wanting it to smoothly fade in the adding and removing of the sticky class to the header-container. At the moment it just appears straight away. Just trying to add some nice subtle effects to the site. Any chance that is possible?

Comment: @dayneh88 you can use `jquery.animate` for this.
Here is the docs http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: thanks @RohanKumar but still a bit confused as to how I go about animating the adding of a class. Are you able to right out some code for me to try out?

Comment: Try to use `fadeTo` like  `$(".header-container").fadeTo('slow', 0.2,function() {$(this).removeClass('sticky');});` in your `else` part.

Comment: nope...i cannot for the life of me get this to work. i have spent hours on it and still cannot figure it out. are you able to write me out the full code and maybe that might work. thanks heaps for your continued effort to help me out.

Comment: For this I have to check your whole code, I think you used `$(".header-container").animate(200).removeClass("sticky");` use it like `$(".header-container").animate({'opacity':0.2}).removeClass("sticky");`